# From a function, how do I add calculations to a list?

Tags: python, list, function

From this function right here:

```
def abs_approx(x,N):  
    sigma=0
    for n in range(1,N+1):
        num=cos((2*n-1)*x)
        denom=(2*n-1)**2
        sigma+=num/denom  
        f= (pi/2) - (4/pi*(sigma))   
    return f
```

How would I append calculations from f into a list, I want to for instance use the range 1 to 5 with x values and the same for N, how do i then add those calculations to a list in the end that i can print out?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) if you don't want to edit your code much:

```
def abs_approx(x,N):  
    sigma=0
    for n in range(1,N+1):
        num=cos((2*n-1)*x)
        denom=(2*n-1)**2
        sigma+=num/denom  
        f= (pi/2) - (4/pi*(sigma))   
        yield f

result = abs_approx(2, 5)

print(list(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

To append calculation results to list within your function, you can do this:

```
def abs_approx(x,N):  
    sigma=0
    f = []
    for n in range(1,N+1):
        num=cos((2*n-1)*x)
        denom=(2*n-1)**2
        sigma+=num/denom  
        f.append((pi/2) - (4/pi*(sigma)))   
    return f
```